# IndexOutOfBoundsException but Error does not give me a Line in the Code

Tags: android

I have updated my app and suddenly getting this error. I cannot make head or tail of it as there is no line in my code.

People have seen this on there phones I have seen on one emulator but on my home machine it works fine. removed database and start again and still nothing

Any ideas would be welcome
Thanks

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:398)
at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:349)
at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:313)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1665)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2695)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show us how you create/set the `Spinner` adapter

Comment: I have fixed it. I was setting a dafault selected from a value saved in database but this did not match to the amount of values I had in the spinner. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it. I was setting a dafault selected from a value saved in database but this did not match to the amount of values I had in the spinner. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction